# Waiting on scripts in URLSession

Tags: javascript, html, swift, parsing, url

I am trying to parse this Tennis statistics Website: https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=3333# .

When I open the page in Chrome an inspect it, there is a div element with the class: "row".

When I make an Url Request in my Swift application, like this:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (dat, response, err) in
            if let error = err{
                print(error)
            }else{
                guard let data = dat else {
                    return
                }
                if let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                    // continue to work with the html string here 
                }else{
                    print("Error no htmlString")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
```

and print out the html, at the place where I hoped to find the div with the class "row", I get a div with the class of "loading" instead.

I think this might be because the scripts on the website haven't run yet.
How can I fix this and let the scripts run and wait for their callback?
Or how else can I resolve this issue?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by loading the link in a webView, and extracting the html after a short delay. 
Here is my code:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.ultimatetennisstatistics.com/playerProfile?playerId=3333#")!
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webview.load(request)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
        self.webview.evaluateJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML") { (was, err) in
            if let doc = was {
                print(doc)
            }else{
                print(err!)
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

Another way would have been to use a headless Browser.